# Скрытие диалогов при изменении history

Tags: gwt, java

В проекте есть несколько history-item, на которые может переходить пользователь. Когда пользователь переходит с address#itemA на address#itemB, диалоги с прошлой страницы истории остаются. Как исправить этот недостаток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть метод [setAutoHideOnHistoryEventsEnabled](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html).

Внутри PopupPanel скрытие диалогов реализовано так, как написал cy6erGn0m (см. метод updateHandlers). При появлении диалога добавляется слушатель истории и сохраняется его HandlerRegistration, при исчезании диалога слушатель истории удаляется через этот HandlerRegistration.

```
// Remove any existing handlers.
if (historyHandlerRegistration != null) {
  historyHandlerRegistration.removeHandler();
  historyHandlerRegistration = null;
}
...
// Create handlers if showing.
if (showing) {
  ...
  historyHandlerRegistration = 
    History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
      if (autoHideOnHistoryEvents) {
        hide();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Создайте [HistoryListener](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/HistoryListener.html) и добавьте его [History.addHistoryListener](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html#addHistoryListener%28com.google.gwt.user.client.HistoryListener%29)(myListener);
У интерфейса предусмотрено событие onHistoryChanged. По этому событию вам придётся закрывать/открывать необходимые диалоги..

**UPD1:**

Ну так это зависит от того, каким образом вы эти диалоги создаёте и от того, какой паттерн вы применяете. В случае MVP вполне можно presenter подписать на историю и при переходе на элемент истории, не связанный с диалогом, диалог может совершить суицид :)

А можно сделать какой-нибудь DialogManager, который бы знал обо всех открытых диалогах и грохал ненужные в случае чего.

Comment: То есть получается, что нужно каждому диалогу иметь свой history-listener? Или можно сделать один history-listener, но непонятно, как он будет находить открытые диалоги и определять, какие из них нужно закрыть?

Comment: см. UPD1

Comment: Спасибо. Получается, если бы этого метода не оказалось готового, лучше всего было бы в обработке хистори смотреть всех детей у RootPanel и удалить все, которые instanceof DialogBox.